# How to set a controller method not to be routed using attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I have applied a route attribute at the controller level, but I want to exclude an action from being routed. Not overriding but excluding the route completely. How can this be achieved?

Let's say I have:

```
[RoutePrefix("promotions")]
[Route("{action=index}")]
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
    // eg.: /promotions
    public ActionResult Index() { ... }

    // eg.: /promotions/archive
    public ActionResult Archive() { ... }

    // eg.: /promotions/new
    public ActionResult New() { ... }

    // eg.: /promotions/edit/5
    [Route("edit/{promoId:int}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int promoId) { ... }

    public void Internal() { ... }
}
```

and I want Internal not to be routed.

I would have expected to find a [DoNotRoute] or [Ignore] attribute, but I didn't find anything like that.

Comment: Are you manually routing Internal, or it's not an action at all?

Comment: It's not an action at all. It's a public method, located at the base controller and its the implementation of an interface.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `[NonAction]` attribute:

```
[NonAction]
public void Internal() { ... }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it has no effect. The action is still showing up in the list of registered routes.

Comment: Try the URL, it shouldn't work. Where are you seeing this list of registered routes?

Comment: Isn't that the same route for Index, Archive and New?

Comment: I've checked it and requests are NOT being routed to this action, which is good. I would have preferred not to see the method listed as a route either, but I think that would be an "aesthetical" concern only. I still believe a DoNotRoute attribute would be a cleaner solution, in the line of the rest of attribute routing configurations. Or maybe, it would suffice to exclude routes of actions with the [NonAction] attribute.